# How can I use jquery events on a list of ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, list

I have an html with a list of ids like:

```
<div id="id0" value="myval0">Click me</div>
<div id="id1" value="myval1">Click me</div>
<div id="id2" value="myval2">Click me</div>
<div id="id3" value="myval3">Click me</div>
```

The list can be generated by the server. I am trying jQuery something of this form to send to the server which id has been clicked:

```
$( "#id0" ).click(function() {
  var urlstring = '/getresult';
alert($("#id0").val());
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlstring,
    data: {
      draft_no: $("#id0").val(),
    },
    success: function(result){
      alert("Function returned with success!")
    }
  });
});
```

In this case I have sent id of the form "id0". But how can I generalise this to "id n" where n is any integer?

Comment: have you tried 
$("#id"+n).click(function(){
});

Comment: An ID can ***not*** contain a space, and you can only have one!

Comment: also remove space between id and 0

Comment: The simple solution is to add a class when you generate them on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this JQuery selector `E[a^=v]` it match all elements `E` that possess an attribute `a` whose value starts width `v`

Your html:

```
<div id="id-1" value="my val 1">Click me</div>
<div id="id-2" value="my val 2">Click me</div>
<div id="id-3" value="my val 3">Click me</div>
```

Your jQuery

```
$('div[id^=id]').click(function() {
  var urlstring = '/getresult';
  var val = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlstring,
    data: {
      draft_no: val,
    },
    success: function(result){
      alert("Function returned with success!")
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Huh? "starts", not "ends".

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "[id^=id]" ).click(function() {
  var urlstring = '/getresult';
alert($(this).val());
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlstring,
    data: {
      draft_no: $(this).val(),
    },
    success: function(result){
      alert("Function returned with success!")
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is writing a generic event handler that takes care of all the `div`s. You cannot do that with IDs. You will have to either give your divs a specific class [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/QE9Uy/)

```
<div id="id 1" value="my val 1" class="mydiv">Click me</div>
<div id="id 2" value="my val 2" class="mydiv">Click me</div>
<div id="id 3" value="my val 3" class="mydiv">Click me</div>

$(".mydiv").click(function() {
alert($(this).attr("value"));
// ....
});
```

or look them up by a container [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ48y/1/)

```
<div id="mycontainer">
<div id="id 1" value="my val 1">Click me</div>
<div id="id 2" value="my val 2">Click me</div>
<div id="id 3" value="my val 3">Click me</div>
</div>

$("#mycontainer").click(function(evt) {
alert($(evt.target).attr("value"));
// ....
});
```